# Differences between 5V DC 350ma vs. 450ma

Tags: voltage, current, battery-charging

I have two A.C adapter chargers giving an output of **`5V DC 350mA`** and the other one with **`5V DC 450mA`**. Is it possible that I could use a **`5V DC 350mA`** to recharge a phone  which came out with **`5V DC 450mA`** charger and vice-versa?

I have searched the google and found that using a lower amperage supply charger for the phone that came out with or requiring higher amperage charger could be damaged by it.

How much does this matter with **`350mA`** and **`450mA`** or what is the difference between them?

Comment: Please read [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings) and rephrase your question to drill in to the details if you still have a question.

Comment: You should be able to switch without a problem if you are going from 350mA to 450mA. That rating is the max amount of current the wall wart is capable of outputting. The load of the device will determine how much current is delivered.

Comment: Please rephrase this question

Comment: @Funkyguy: Edited the question.

Comment: @cpx Thanks! I hope my last comment didn't come off as too blunt.  was in a hurry.  Looks fine now.

Comment: The answer really depends if it is the wall adapter or the phone which regulates charging to a safe level.  If it is the phone, then a "supply" with a higher possible amperage may be used.  But if the phone relies on the "charger" to provide only current appropriate to the battery, then using a higher rating is risky.

Comment: cpx: If the charging circuitry in the phone requires an input of 5 volts from a supply which is capable of supplying at least 450 mA and it's connected to a supply which is designed to supply a maximum of 350 mA, then the phone will load the supply more heavily than it was designed to be and the supply could be damaged by overheating. I'd provide greater detail in an answer, but it appears answering has been turned off. :-(

Answer (score 0):

So you're talking about a wall USB charger correct? Assuming so, both will work fine. The 450ma charger will charge the battery more quickly, as it can provide more current @5v (hence more power).

Comment: It's an AC adapter. Any idea how quickly will it be able to charge compared to the other one? Is the difference very significant?

Comment: The Photon is correct, and you would do well to follow his link and learn more. With the right google key words, you definitely could have discovered the answer! EDIT- What's the percentage increase from 350 to 450? That's roughly how much quicker.

Comment: From one [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/34771/50938) at the link The Photon just posted it appears that 350ma could take damage the device if it needs 450ma. Do I understand this?

Comment: See now we're getting into details... only you can tell us what the minimum charging current is for your device. Look at the section on the current limit. Any well designed charger will not allow you to draw more than it's rated power, but don't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

Higher the current the faster the charging.  If for some reason your phone cannot take 450mA it will only draw 350mA from the higher capacity charger.
Basic difference between voltage and current is that voltage is pushed to the device while current is pulled by it.  So using a 6v 350mA charger will harm your device.